# Find all of the Eigenvalues of T

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let there be $V$, vector space from a finite dimenstion contains all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ 
$T:V$$\rightarrow $ $V$ linear transformation such that:

- $T^2$ = $T$
- $Im(T)$ $\neq$ $V$
- $Im(T)$ $\neq$ {$\vec{0}$}

Find all of the **Eigenvalues** of $T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $v\in V$, $v=\bigl(v-T(v)\bigr)+T(v)$. Now, not that$$T\bigl(v-T(v)\bigr)=T(v)-T^2(v)=0$$and that therefore $v-T(v)$ belongs to the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $0$. Besides,$$T\bigl(T(v)\bigr)=T(v),$$and so $T(v)$ belongs to the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $1$. So, $V$ is the direct sum of the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $0$ with the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $1$, and therefore the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. But if $0$ was not an eigenvalue, then $T$ would be the identity map, in which case $\operatorname{Im}(T)=V$. And if $1$ was not an eigenvalue, then $T$ would be the null map, in which case $\operatorname{Im}(T)=\left\{\vec0\right\}$. So, the set of all eigenvalues is $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

$Im(T) ≠ V$ says that the transformation is not "full rank"
At least one eigenvalue is $0.$

$Im(T) ≠ \{0\}$ nor is the transformation a zero matrix that flattens everything to the zero vector.

$T^2 = T.$ The eigenvalues will be roots of this equation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\text{Im } T \neq V \land \text{Im } T \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, we can conclude that T has a nontrivial kernel, but also a nontrivial Image. Suppose $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of T with the eigenvalue $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. Then $$T(v) = \lambda v$$ but further since T is a projection $$T \circ T(v) = T(\lambda v) = T(v)$$ and since T is linear we get that $$\lambda T(v) = T(v)$$ which is true for $\lambda \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ since for the case $\lambda=0$ we get $v \in \ker T$.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ satisfies the polynomial $f(x) = x(x -1)$. The minimal polynomial must divide $f$ and so the possibilities are $x, x - 1, x(x-1)$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem the first two conditions imply that $T = 0$ or $T = I$, but both of these are ruled out by the hypothesis on the image of $T$. Hence the minimal polynomial must be $f(x) = x(x-1)$. The eigenvalues are the roots of minimal polynomial.